# iOS - How to unit test deep links to ensure they can be processed app-side

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I'm hoping this isn't too general of a question and won't get flagged..what is the best practice or best steps needed to be taken in order to write a unit test for a deep link..to ensure it can be processed. I'm using Xcode's XCTestCase. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A specific answer really depends on how you've structured your app and what components are therefore responsible for reacting to a deep link.

At a high level I would try to:

1. Extract the behavior I want to test (deep linking) into a component responsible for this behavior (and ideally just this behavior). In this case maybe that means the app delegate hands the link off to some Router class which can parse the link and navigate accordingly.
2. Create an instance of that component in my test with injected test doubles for any dependencies.
3. Make sure I can assert on the result so I know if it behaved as expected. For a test of deep links that might mean the test inspects modifications to injected view controllers. Alternately a Router might return a sequence of RouteActions that need to be performed, each of which can be separately tested independently or you might assert that the first Router performs part of the work and hands off the rest to another Router responsible for navigating within some subsection of the app.

Depending on your app there might be multiple initial states against which you want to test the same deep link; signed in vs signed out, linking to data the app has not yet loaded, and so on.